# Choosing in either of the functions

Tags: c#, .net

Let me give an example and try to explain what I want to ask:

Lets suppose I have functions called `Func1`, `Func2`, `Fucn3`... so on. All these functions have same signature. Then, there is this other function `Call(String str)`. Now based upon paramenter passed to `Call`, I want to call one of the three functions. i.e. if `str == "Func1"` call Func1, if `str == "Func2"` call Func2, if `str == "Func3"` call Func3 ... and so on. Is there a way to do this without using conditional statements?

Comment: Does those functions share the same signature (parameters and return value)?

Comment: Where are these functions defined?

Comment: In a class. Lets say `Class1`. all these functions are in the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use polymorphism for this.

If you have a few classes implementing the same interface, you can pass the object with the behaviour you want to your function and call it directly, since the behaviour would be encapsulated in the passed in object.

See the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for examples and details.

Comment: Kind of overkill for this question.  But in general, you are right. +1

Comment: @J0HN - Can't determine if this is overkill, as the OP only posted a rather sketchy description and no code...

Comment: This example looks good. However, to determine which object to instantiate, AFAIK it seems I would have to again use conditional statement.

Comment: @harshit - When **choosing** behaviour, you have to use some sort of conditional _somewhere_.

Comment: @Oded yes I understand that. Although, for implementing other options to implement this, as suggested in other answers, i.e. reflection/ or using a Dictionay object do not need conditional statements(atleast not for choosing either of the functions)

Comment: Okay, if we don't look on dictionary object method (because it would require as many key-value pairs as there are number of methods), still using reflection do not require conditional statements

Comment: @harshit - The problem with reflection is that you loose strong typing (say you change a method name and forget to change the reflection code).

Comment: Yes, I can see the problem. Just out of curosity, what if the signatures were different. Then i don't think I would be able to use this method. What then?

Comment: @harshit - You couldn't use most of these options if the signatures were different.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is some kind of table lookup:

```
//assuming your functions receive string and return int

Dictionary<string, Func<string, int>> methods = {
    {"Func1", Func1},
    {"Func2", Func2},
    {"Func3", Func3}
}

void call(String input){
    if (methods.HasKey(input)){
       int result = methods[input]("I'm a parameter");
    }
}
```

Another way is to use reflection:

```
void call(String input){
    var func = yourobject.GetType().GetMethod(input);
    if (func!=null){
        int result = func.Invoke(object, "I'm a parameter");
    }
}
```

First approach is a bit more verbose, but you obtain full control on what functions are mapped to what strings. The latter approach requires less code, but should be used carefully.

Comment: What is wrong with the second method? I mean why should it be used carefully?

Comment: Also, for the one with function map, what if I introduce a new function and forget to make an entry in the dictionary. That would fail the prupose. Also, you will have to make as many entries as are the number of functions increasing memory compleciations. However, your second method does not require the same.

Comment: @harshit What if you have function `DoSomethingHorrible` in the same class that contains `Func1`, `Func2`, etc. The function is not intended to be used with this calling convention. Now, reflection approach does not prevent you from calling `DoSomethingHorrible`. That's why you **must** be careful with such an approach. The former approach, as I've mentioned, requires more typing, but allows for creating a manageable 'white-list' of functions.
If the number of functions increase so it turns to memory issues, I think it's much better to switch to `Strategy` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The usual alternative to `if-else` in these situations is `switch`. For example:

```
switch (str) {
    case "Func1": Func1(); break;
    case "Func2": Func2(); break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentException("Unrecognised function name", "str");
        break;
}
```

This may or may not produce more efficient code than a series of `if` and `else if` depending on how smart the compiler is (I've never looked into it, although I'm now quite interested).

Another approach would be to borrow an idea from Perl: make a `Dictionary<string, Func<Whatever>>` and add entries for the different key values to it, then you can look up the required function object in it when you need to.

Comment: In both of the solutions you proposed, I would have to repeat making an entry. Also, if I add a new function at some point of time in the future, I would have to remember to make an entry here also.

Comment: Indeed you would, but you've got to map from strings to function objects somehow. The only way you can avoid building a mapping whether it be in a `Dictionary` or a `switch` is to use reflection as some have suggested, which then seriously constrains what the strings and member names can be so might not be suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use delegates as well. Sample code

```
   delegate int Arithm(int x, int y);

public class CSharpApp
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DoOperation(10, 2, Multiply);
        DoOperation(10, 2, Divide);
    }

    static void DoOperation(int x, int y, Arithm del)
    {
        int z = del(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }

    static int Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

    static int Divide(int x, int y)
    {
        return x / y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks intersting in the first glance, however I would like to pass a `String`  to DoOperation

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch or select statements for it, 
 like below

```
Between the button Sub and End Sub code add the folowing

Dim creamcake As String
 Dim DietState As String

creamcake = TextBox1.Text

Select Case creamcake

Case "Eaten"
DietState = "Diet Ruined"
Case "Not Eaten"
DietState = "Diet Not Ruined"
Case Else
DietState = "Didn't check"


End Select

MsgBox DietState
```

Comment: The question is tagged with C#, not VB.NET

Comment: now honestly how different are they when it comes to basic functionality like this???

Comment: To some minds, very. Not everyone who can read C# can read VB.NET easily. And if you find this to be easy, why not write in C# to begin with?

Comment: well I guess you are right, anyway it wasnt the only reply suggesting to use select, hope your find the answer you looking for.